# Security video missing time and frames

Tags: keyframes, avi, footage

Why does a DVR or CCTV system randomly drop time or frames? I am viewing footage that says it is 12fps but, it is scanning at 10fps. These files were exported as AVI.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually dropped frames are down to processor or disk bottleneck issues. If the frame cannot be compressed or stored in time, most applications will drop in order to move on to the next one.

The solution is often simple - increase the processing power or disk i/o speed.